# Show that any quadrilateral can become cyclic by changing angles.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, quadrilateral

Given a convex quadrilateral with given side lengths $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ in that order (meaning that side a intersects $d$, $b$; side $b$ intersect $a$, $c$ e.t.c.), show that it is possible to "make" this a *cyclic* quadrilateral just by changing the angles while preserving the side lengths and order in which they appear.

Comment: Make a drawing.

Comment: Intuitively, you can take "large" circle, with a chain of chords of length $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ (with $a$ and $d$ not touching). By shrinking the circle, the endpoints of the $a$ and $d$ chords get closer together until, for some magic radius, those endpoints meet.

Comment: Intuitively, as well, you can only shrink the circle around the chain until it reaches the size at which one of the chords is a diameter. A convex quadrilateral that is very "thin" along that chord might actually fail to be able to be cyclic, maybe?

Comment: Good tip, thanks! I am constructing the proof right now. I will post an answer when I am done